# iOS Find the box given a point in space

Tags: ios, touch

I have a very interesting problem I couldn't find a solution for.
Given a set ox rectangles or box in space, and given the coordinate of a touch, I would find the box the touch point belongs to.
At first, I used the euclidena distance of the point from the center of the rectangles.

But, obviously, this doesn't always work. Assume the following figure with 2 boxes, with centers a and c, respectively:

```
----------
|        |
|        |
|   a    |
|        |
|        |
|   x    |
----------
|        |
|   c    |
|        |
----------
```

The touch point is "x" and it belongs to box "a". With my algorithm, x is nearest to c than a, which is wrong.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you're making this way more complicated than it needs to be.  If you capture the touch event, you can check to see if the touch.view is the same as box a or box c.  Maybe take a look at UITapGestureRecognizer (I think that's the class), and add the gesture recognizer to your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CGRectContainsPoint` method does all the work for you. Say for example you used a tap gesture.

```
-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(box.frame, point)) {
       NSLog@("Point is in Box");
    }       
}
```

Comment: I have to get used to read the manual!!Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the assumption you're **not** working with views, rather you're dealing with a model containing different rectangular areas.

You simply traverse the list of boxes, and use the function `BOOL CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point);`

For example (assuming your rectangles are boxed in NSValues, to be stored in an NSArray):

```
NSArray* arrayOfRects = ...;
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(xTouch, yTouch);

CGRect rectResult = CGRectNull;

for (NSValue* rectObj in arrayOfRects) {
    CGRect rect = [rectObj CGRectValue];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point)) {
        rectResult = rect;
        break;
    };
}

if (!CGRectEqualToRect(rectResult, CGRectNull)) {
    // Found a matching rect!
}
else {
    // Touch was outside of any recognised rect
}
```

This solution won't deal with overlapping rectangles. If you need this, you'll need to keep a collection of matches, as so:

```
NSArray* arrayOfRects = ...;
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(xTouch, yTouch);

NSMutableArray* rectResultArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSValue* rectObj in arrayOfRects) {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([rectObj CGRectValue], point)) {
        [rectResultArray addObject:rectObj];
    };
}

if (rectResultArray.count > 0) {
    // Found matching rects!
}
else {
    // Touch was outside of any recognised rect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right is realizing that you cannot use the distance to the center of the box.  You can try to get fancy and code this yourself or you can use a pre-made function `CGRectContainsPoint()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
//get the location of the touch
touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
location = [touch locationInView:view];

//check if touchpoint belongs to a box
if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.boxA.frame, location))
{
     NSLog(@"Touchpoint is in box A");
}
else if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.boxB.frame, location))
{
     NSLog(@"Touchpoint is in box B");
}
else
{
     NSLog(@"Touchpoint is not in box");
}
```